# MATLAB, cannot append existing .mat file

Tags: matlab

I'm new on MATLAB and I having problems with saving and append variables, so, here is my problem. I'm trying to save variables with the following command: `save('tes.mat','thisisatest'); save('test.mat','this_test_2','-append');` that code work just fine, giving me `test.mat` file contains 2 variables. So, I got `test.mat` file now, on another class im trying to append more variables into that file `save(tes.mat,'test_3','-apppend');` the code doesn't give an error but the variable `test_3` wont append onto `tes.mat`. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you copy and paste your exact code? The code in your question seems to have typos and missing quotes, and I can't tell which is an error in your question and which is an actual error in your code.

Comment: You wrote "`apppend`", with 3 p's.

Comment: Maybe save(tes.mat,'test_3','-apppend'); should be with  'test.mat' ??